Altium custom query allowing specific pad to be closer to the board edge
I have a PCB Edge connector in which two pads are a bit closer to the edge. My default rule is >=0.5mm, but for those pads I would like to set >= 0.35mm. I tried to write a custom query, but none of my attempts worked:
HasPad('J14-14') = True 
(PadName = 'J14-14')     
(ComponentDesignator = 'J14' AND PadName = '19')
(Name = 'J14-19')


Is there a way to target these pads only for the Board Outline Clearance?

What do you mean by it doesnt work? Do the queries not match with the pad? Is there something wrong with DRC results despite the query matching the pad? What is the result when you hit "Test Queries"?

None of those queries are valid

Pads are not a plane feature; you're looking at the incorrect rule set. Please show the exact violation that you are having trouble with.

I would just do this globally for the part and not try and search a specific pad. Another way to do this is just waive the DRC violation for special cases like this. You also don't need to put '= TRUE' on the end, you can just put haspad('J14') and try that.
TIP: You can also test querys with the button in the upper right corner to see the number of objects detected by the query, if it's 0 it's likely that it isn't working in your case.

In your picture, I see the rule PCB Edge twice. Altium doesn't allow you to have more than one rule with the same name. Probably your query works, but the error you get is about the rule's name.

nowox - Hi, (a) In this answer, you said: "In your picture {...}" but you asked the question and I guess you're referring to the image in the question. In that case, don't you mean to say "In my picture"?  (b) Since you asked the question, and have now written an answer to it, that indicates you have solved your problem. Therefore please consider áccepting the "best" answer (this self-answer or another answer) to make it clear for future readers what the solution was, and to effectively close your question. TY

@SamGibson Yes I am referring to, and answering my question. However. I usually prefer to break the link between me asking and me answering. This is why I treated the question as a question asked by somebody. Before accepting the answer I should make some checks on my side because in the end, I solved my issue differently.
